# How to determine if users have the default password in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I know that I can query the "dba_users_with_defpwd" table, but I've seen reports that for some accounts (mainly SYS and SYSTEM) even if you provide a new non-trivial password during install, they will be shown as having the default password.

Is there any way to verify the users with default passowrds other than manually comparing the "sys.users$" and "sys.defalut_pwd$" tables?

NOTE: I don't have direct access to the environment, I just receive the user tables to check for compliance with the company's rules.

Comment: Try to logon with default passwords.

Comment: I need to provide some documentation about this process and prove that the passwords are not default, mostly non-tecnhical people will review my tests. Comparing the "sys.users$" and "sys.defalut_pwd$" tables is the way to go? Since it will be easier to show them a comparison between two excel files instead of screenshot from Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SYS and SYSTEM accounts are incorrectly listed in DBA_USERS_WITH_DEFPWD in 12c (Doc ID 2173962.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2173962.1)

> SYS and SYSTEM have that flag set a database create time, and the flag
>   doesn't clear until the first password change AFTER the database is
>   created. So it may or may not be a default password, but it if it
>   isn't default, it's one that hasn't been changed since the database
>   was created and therefore should be changed.

If you do not have access to this, then:

https://mandysandhu.com/2017/10/20/oracle-12c-syssystem-accounts-are-incorrectly-listed-in-dba_users_with_defpwd/

Comment: Thanks. Since I need to provide some documentation about this process and prove that the passwords are not default,  comparing the "sys.users$" and "sys.defalut_pwd$" tables is the way to go?

Comment: @Gleisson Oracle provided the view `dba_users_with_defpwd`. Use it, with keeping in mind the above.